# Multiple bulk inserts in MongoDB - Performance

Tags: java, mongodb, bulkinsert

I understand about the performance gain between regular inserts and `bulk inserts`.

My question is that, how best is to do multiple bulk operations, where each operations inserts a good number (Min 15000) of records. Or is there any better approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand the specific problem well, but in general terms I would do it in the following way:

- I would define a setting for maximum number of rows to be inserted
- I would define a setting for maximum time to be allowed to pass before a scheduled row is being inserted
- I would have a thread with a queue of record params to be inserted
- whenever a new row is needed to be inserted I would add it to the queue
- whenever a row is added to the queue, if the number of rows reaches the maximum number of rows, I would issue the bulk insert and clear the queue
- when the queue is initialized/cleared I would set the timer to 0
- when the time elapsed reaches the maximum time defined in the setting, I would execute the bulk insert and would clear the queue

Comment: Your approach is essentially for sequential bulk-insert (One after another). My question is for multiple bulk-inserts that comes from different parts of application (different bolts - storm way). How expensive is to do, say 30 bulk-inserts where each bulk-insert handles minimum of 15K records?

Comment: @KavithaMadhavaraj, my suggestion is to use a separate thread for bulk inserts, so you can actually run one at a time. You can run it asynchronously as well. As about the question in your comment, actually that depends on your current situation. How you gather the data, how many columns does the target table have, how many select queries are running on average and what is their complexity. You also need to avoid flooding a server, it is better to wait for a while than to crash the server...

Comment: Execute one bulk-insert at a time? That makes sense.

Comment: @KavithaMadhavaraj, yes, basically this is desirable. It depends on your situation whether you need to execute more (for instance you get hundreds of thousands of data each minute), but if you get close to this desirable situation, then you are on the right track.

Comment: MongoDB driver will split batch of 15k operations to smaller size. I think default size is batch of 1000 operations. So batch of 15k will not give you any performance boost but bit drag. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/

Comment: @Saleem, in that case, batches of 1000 seem to be more reasonable, with maximum time reduced to 15x smaller.

Comment: In my experience batch of 300 to 500 perform better than default.